# Get substring after and before '-' character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this kind of strings in a table:

- AM-65-800
- AM-75/86-650
- D-27-600

What I'm trying to do is to get only the middle part, for example:

- 65
- 75/86
- 27

Basically the substring after and before the '-' Char

I tried this (from an example in here):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Product.Name, LEN(LEFT(Product.[Name], CHARINDEX ('-', Product.[Name]))) + 1, LEN(Product.[Name]) - LEN(LEFT(Product.[Name], CHARINDEX ('-', Product.[Name]))) - LEN(RIGHT(Product.[Name], LEN(Producto.[Name]) - CHARINDEX ('-', Product.[Name]))) - 1)
FROM Product
```

But it gives me this error:

```
[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. (537)
```

Being honest, I don't know how to solve the error because I don't understand the solution from the example. what can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems much more convoluted than it needs to be. For example, `LEN(LEFT(Product.[Name], CHARINDEX ('-', Product.[Name]))) + 1` could be simplified to `CHARINDEX('-', Product.Name) + 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is ParseName()

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max)='AM-65-800'

Select parsename(replace(@S,'-','.'),2)
```

**Returns**

```
65
```

Comment: This is clever. Introduced in SQL2012.. going to have keep this in mind.

Comment: @Forty3 Actually undocumented in 2008

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTRING` with start and lengths calculated based on position of the '-':

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABC-65-DEF', 
                 CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF') + 1, 
                 CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF', CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF') + 1) - CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF') - 1)
```

Basically, it finds the first instance of the '-' (`CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF')`) and then the second instance of '-' (`CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF', CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-65-DEF') + 1)`) and grabs the substring inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

This will work to find the middle part on older SQL Servers up to and including 2008.

```
DECLARE @SomeText VARCHAR(100) = 'AM-75/86-650'
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@SomeText, LEN(@SomeText) - CHARINDEX('-', @SomeText)),  
           CHARINDEX('-', RIGHT(@SomeText, LEN(@SomeText) - CHARINDEX('-', @SomeText)))-1)
```

Returns: '75/86'